# How we add .crx file and integrate idm to google chrome manually?

Tags: google-chrome, idm

I am using IDM and I want to integrate it with google chrome and due to the recent update in Google Chrome. Google Chrome can't allow me to add idm extension in google chrome. Is there any option or help that I can integrate with my Google Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow these steps:

1. Turn on the developer option from chrome
2. press the update and update the extensions
3. then just drag and drop the .crx file into extension and press the add extension

Answer (score 0):

To do that just Drag & drop the IDM CRX file into the chrome extension tab and allow the extension by tapping on Add Extension button.

That's it.

IDM extension will be added to your chrome browser.

references:
idmlover(dot)com